# WordPress Menu item > Sub menu Class update

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I'm a newbie to **WordPress core** and **development process**. As I have a little knowledge of **WordPress functions**. **But I need the help from you guys**.

Actually, i'm developing my first theme and i already have the **CSS for my menu**. The menu has been registered in **functions.php.**

I've used the **code posted below** to add my class **"mainnav-section".**

```
<?php 
              $args = [
                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'container'      => 'ul',
                'container_class'=> '',
                'menu_class'     => 'mainnav-section'
              ];
              wp_nav_menu($args);
          ?>
```

**And it executed this.**

```
<ul id="menu-header" class="mainnav-section">
    <li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-511">
        <a href="http://#">Latest</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-512">
                <a href="http://#">HardFork</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-513">
        <a href="http://#">Innovations</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

All I want to to do is to add my **CSS class** to **main-menu items**, **sub-menu** and **list items**. Because I have the **CSS and JS completed** to get the **desired menu.**

Comment: You have to customize the [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/)

Comment: What are the classes you need to add and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will add a class called `class-here` to all menu items:

```
/**
 * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
 *
 * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
 * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
 * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 *
 * @return Array $classes
 */
function theme_prefix_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $dpeth ) {

    $classes[] = 'class-here';

    return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'theme_prefix_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

You could add this to your themes `functions.php` file. There's a bunch of other hooks when the WordPress WP Nav Walker creates the menus - [Check out The Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook)

Comment: @howdy-mcgee i want to add the class to **mainmenu item** **submenu** and its **items**. 
<br>
`<li class="mainmenu item"> Google</li>
<ul class=sub-menu>
<li>Google sub-menu item1</li>
<li>Google sub-menu item2</li>
<li>Google sub-menu item3</li>
</ul>`

Comment: @tassawarr The above code will add the class to all **mainmenu items** and all **submenu items** - Your comment has the classes _incrementing_ which isn't in your original question, is that just an example or are you specifically looking for an incrementing class?